# How do I add toggle drawer to my navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add burger menu button to my navigation but everytime I try to do this it can't find `toggleDrawer()` or `openDrawer()` it works well when swiping but I would like to also toggle it with button also. Where do i need to add this functionality that it would work and I am using the v5 of `react-navigation`

My navigation file is as following.

```
function DrawerScreen() {
  return (
    <DrawerStack.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <DrawerStack.Screen name="Home" component={GamesScreen} />
    </DrawerStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export function MainPage() {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashPage">
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="SplashPage"
        component={SplashPage}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={() => {
          return {
            headerTitle: '',
            headerTransparent: true,
            headerShown: false,
            //  headerLeft: (navigation) => (
            //   <Icon
            //   name={'menu'}
            //   style={styles.hamburgerMenu}
            //   onPress={() => toggleDrawer()}
            // /> 
            // ),
          }
        }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen 
        name="Games"
        component={DrawerScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Games',
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerShown: true,
          headerLeft: () => (null),
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 30,
            textAlign: 'center'
          }
        }}
      />
           <MainStack.Screen
        name="Kings"
        component={Kings}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Kings',
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerShown: true,
          headerBackTitleVisible: false,
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 30,
            textAlign: 'center'
          },
        }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="Centurions"
        component={Centurions}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Centurions',
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerShown: true,
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 36,
            textAlign: 'center'
          },
        }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="DrinkOrDare"
        component={DrinkOrDare}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Drink Or Dare',
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerShown: true,
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 30,
            textAlign: 'center'
          },
        }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="MostLikely"
        component={MostLikely}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Most likely...',
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerShown: true,
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 30,
            textAlign: 'center'
          },
        }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="NeverHaveIEver"
        component={NeverHaveIEver}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Never have I ever...',
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerShown: true,
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 30,
            textAlign: 'center'
          },
        }}
      />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your stack navigator a screen of your drawer navigator instead of the other way around you have access to the `navigation` object of the drawer, which allows you to call `navigation.toggleDrawer()` inside the `MainPage` component.

Here's an example:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator();

// ...

function DrawerScreen() {
  return (
    <DrawerStack.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <DrawerStack.Screen name="MainPage" component={MainPage} />
    </DrawerStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export function MainPage({navigation}) {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashPage">
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="Games"
        component={Home}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Icon
              name={'menu'}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.toggleDrawer();
              }}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I left out some imports, styles and screens to make the code easier to read.